# Repast: Batch run cause UTF-8 corrupted characters

Tags: repast-simphony

My model has a DataWriter class to ouput a csv file which contains some UTF-8 characters in the headerline. It's showing properly in the output csv file when I run the model in GUI mode. However, when I run it in batch mode, the headerline UTF-8 character in the output file is corrupted.

What's the underly cause of this issue in batch mode?